# In wx.Python.aui, how do I detect/pass events between panes?

Tags: wxpython

I do not code very often and therefore forget some things quickly. However I have been tinkering (working in) python and wx.python for a couple of years and finally came across AGW.AUI and thought it would be useful to upgrade a few of my in-house apps. However, I now have a hiccup. How do I detect/pass events between panels which are loaded and then hidden or shown via the aui.AUIManager()?

I have a small app using wxpython:

```
    class paneldescription(wx.Panel):

      ….panel layout with a list

      self.grid.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.OnItemSelected)

      def OnItemSelected(self, evt)


    class WorkingPanel(wx.Panel):

      ….panel layout of multiple  wx.StaticText and wxTextCtrl


    class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

       b = workbook()

       pnl1 = paneldescription()
       pnl2 = WorkingPanel()

       b.add pnl1
       b.add pnl2

      self.pnl1.grid.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.OnItemSelected)

      def OnItemSelection(self, evt):

        get selected item from pnl1
        set data in pnl2
```

This works well in wx.Frame.   Now I am converting it to AUI and adding more panels. How do I
1) detect the OnItemSelect in paneldescription and 
2) pass it to WorkingPanel

using the AUI manager?

On my first try I simply copied the above Bind statement to the AUI code. It told me there was no item called pnl1.

I then changed it to:

```
   self._mgr.GetPane("LocList").grid.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED,
   self.OnLocSelected)
```

LocList is created by:

```
    self._mgr.AddPane(self.CreateLocCtrl(), aui.AuiPaneInfo().Name("LocList").
    Caption("Location List").CenterPane().CloseButton(False).MinimizeButton(False))
```

This returns

```
  AuiPaneInfo has no object  grid  (grid is the name of the list in the initial panel.)
```

When I remove that reference, it returns

```
  AuiPaneInfo has no object Bind
```

Please help.

Thank you

Warren

Answer (score 0):

I took the original AUI sample as a model for my application. After more searching I finally found another example where the pages were not added in a sub-function, but a the top level of the frame _init code.

I realized that I had no instances of my panel descriptions so I re-arranged my code along these lines and now I have pn1=descriptionpanel so I can reference pn1.OnItemSelected.

Just a logic error on my part.

The newer example is at http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/09/the-%E2%80%9Cbook%E2%80%9D-controls-of-wxpython-part-2-of-2/

I guess my confusion was helped by the lack of AUI examples with activity. All of the examples I have found only show how to add panes and bind menu actions.

W